# Baldi - Stochastic Calculus - Exercise about construsction of Stratonovich integral

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value

I need to prove that $$ \lim_n \sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}  W(\frac{i}{2^n}) ( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) ) \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}W_1^2 - \frac{1}{2}$$ in $L^2$.

where $W$ is a standard Wiener process.

So I started computing

$$E[( \sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}  W(\frac{i}{2^n}) ( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) ) + \frac{1}{2}(1-W_1^2)  )^2]$$

and I split have that, after expanding the square:

$$E[( \sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}  W(\frac{i}{2^n}) ( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) ))^2]=\frac{1}{2}$$

by independence the Gaussian distribution of independent increments.

Then, the double-product term $$\frac{1}{2} E[(1-W_1^2) \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}  W(\frac{i}{2^n}) ( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) )) ] = 0 $$ since it's a standard Wiener process and by independence of increments

The last term to compute is

$$ \frac{1}{4} E[(1-W_1^2)^2)]  = \frac{1}{4} E[1+W_1^4 - 2 W_1^2 ] = \frac{1}{4} (1+3-2)=\frac{1}{2} $$

using that $E[W_1^2] = 1$ and $E[W_1^4] = 3$.

But in this way the sum is $1$ and not $0$... so what am I missing?

Comment: I think that the error is in the computation of the expectation of the double product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expectation numbers are incorrect, you could see that in your proof, your solution is independent of $n$...

First notice that

$$ W_1^2= \sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}  W(\frac{i+1}{2^n})^2- W(\frac{i}{2^n})^2$$
$$ W_1^2= \sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}\left(  W(\frac{i+1}{2^n})+ W(\frac{i}{2^n})\right)\left(  W(\frac{i+1}{2^n})- W(\frac{i}{2^n})\right)$$

Therefore, by factorizing, we have
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}  W(\frac{i}{2^n}) ( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) ) + \frac{1}{2}(1-W_1^2) =\frac{1}{2}\left[1-\sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}   ( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) )^2\right]$$

You want to calculate

$$E\left[\frac{1}{4}\left[1-\sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}   ( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) )^2\right]^2\right]$$

The variance of a Brownian motion increment is known, we have
$$E\left[\sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}   ( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) )^2\right] =\sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}\frac{1}{2^n }=1$$

Finally,

$$E\left[\left[\sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}   ( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) )^2\right]^2\right]=E\left[\sum_{i,j=0}^{2^n -1}   ( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) )^2 (W(\frac{j+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{j}{2^n}) )^2\right]$$

or
$$\sum_{i,j=0, i \ne j}^{2^n -1}   E\left[( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) )^2 (W(\frac{j+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{j}{2^n}) )^2\right]+\sum_{i=0}^{2^n -1}   E\left[( W(\frac{i+1}{2^n}) - W(\frac{i}{2^n}) )^4\right]$$

Increments are independent , and you know the 4th moment of a Brownian motion, you can conclude when you make $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer! In the last line, I have a question about the two sums: the first sum I should get $\frac{1}{2}$ as sending $n$ to infinity, by using independence of increments. WWhile in the second sum I should get $3$, right?

Comment: The first term of the last equation should converge to $1$ and the second one to $0$

Comment: That is what you should get $\frac{3}{(2^N)^2}*2^N$

Comment: Try it, the same approach works, there will be a different sign when you factorize.

Comment: yes, it is the same